# Does recombination occur in both chromatid of a chromosome with homologous chromosome? Or only 1 chromatid participate in crossing over?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, molecular-genetics

A chromosome has two chromatids. In meiosis weather both chromatid participate in crossing over or just only 1 chromatid does?
[image]

So, I am asking whether 1 turquoise and 1 purple chromatid participate in crossing over or both chromatid of turquoise and purple chromatid participate on 1 to 1 basis?

Answer (score 2):

The diagram you provide is just a schematic, showing a simple version to clarify what is happening in a crossover. It seems that [at least once crossover has to occur in each bivalent for normal chromosome segregation to take place. This is called obligate crossover.](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fcell.2021.681123/full#:%7E:text=An%20obligate%20crossover%20must%20occur,sister%20chromatids%20have%20been%20described.) Multiple crossovers do take place, but in eukaryotes this is [usually limited to be four crossovers or less](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3478297/) for each chromosome pair.

Answer (score 1):

I think like that , different alleles coding for different traits are present on different positions on two chromatids
So both can participate in the recombination  only when chromatids of torquoise and purple have contrasting characters present on each chromatid
Conclusion :- both chromatids of a chromosome will participate in recombination but at different time

Comment: Different time means in different cell cycle? So in same cell cycle can both chromatid recombine?

Comment: Different time means in one cycle as there are no only one  trait to recombine in one cycle , for eg. If two genes coding for blonde hair and tall height separately but present on a same chromatid then they will recombine with the chromatid having respective alleles on non - homologous chromosomes at different time , as one chromatid can not perform two recombination at a same time , it was my opinion!